# How to inherit constructor into class method in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have one base class constructor. from that i want to inherit into class method. But it showing the error like  **TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'**

Here is my code snippet.

```
class A:
  def __init__(self,name):
    self.name = name
  def m1(self):
    print(self.name)
class B(A):
 @classmethod
 def m2(cls):
    super(B,cls).__init__(cls.m1)
b=B('siddarth')
b.m2 ()
```

Here it is another example. but without having any parameters in constructor it is working fine.

```
 class A:
  def __init__(self):
    print('This is constructor method..!!')
class B(A):
 @classmethod
 def m2(cls):
    super(B,cls).__init__(cls)
b=B('siddarth')
b.m2()
```

Comment: Please add the error.

Comment: what is `m2` supposed to do? it isn't clear

Comment: Are you sure `m2` should be `classmethod` ?

Comment: m2 is the classmethod name

Comment: @user98 no, I can see that it is the name of the classmethod, *what is it supposed to do*? The code you've written makes no sense. Why are you calling `__init__` in the classmethod?

Comment: Note, because you are using a classmethd, and passing the class object, so `super(B,cls).__init__` is being resolved as the `__init__` attribute on `cls`, so it's actually acting as a descriptor lookup, in which case, function descriptors don't bind the class to the method like it would an instance, so it's returning just the plain `__init__` method, it's not clear what you mean to pass to the superclass `__init__` here though

Answer (score 0):

You can code it like this:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self,name):
    self.name = name
  def m1(self):
    print(self.name)
class B(A):
 def __init__(self, cls):
    super(B, self).__init__(cls)
b=B('siddarth')
b.m1()
```

#### OUTPUT

`siddarth`

Comment: no, you can call `super` in other methods too, but perhaps this is what the OP intends.

Comment: we can inherit the m1 method directly. using  super().m1()

Comment: @user98 what? why would you use `super().m1()`? that makes no sense here.

Comment: what i am saying is, when i inherit constructor without having any parameters into class method that is working fine. but when i adding to the parameters to the constructor after i am unable to inherit into the class method. that is my problem.